# Real life applications of severable complex variables functions theory and complex geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, applications, several-complex-variables

I'm studying several complex variables functions and complex geometry this semester, I knows that complex analysis has applications in electrodynamics and fluid mechanics, and differential geometry has real life applications such as computational conformal geometry, and I also know complex geometry has applications in theoretical physics, but what is the real life applications of several complex variables functions and complex geometry?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question (not just at face value; for _meta_ reasons like what constitutes a _real-life application_?), but am not sure it's a good fit for Math.SE (not focused, opinion-based, arguably not strictly about mathematics).